# WPF Telerik - How to tell the row number from inside a RadGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview

My case is this - I have template set for every column in my radGridView however I want to make a change in appearance   if the current row if the 2nd row.
I guess I will easily use triggers for something like:

```
<Style targetType = "telerik:GridViewCell">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="**CurrentRowNumber**"
               Value="2">
         <Trigger.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Red"/>
         </Trigger.Setters>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I want to achieve this using xaml only.
thanks!.

Comment: I suppose it will be not so easy, you need some DataContext where items has index.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I know I have this option but I can't allow myself to mess with the data model, I need a solution using only the xaml.

Comment: Well, in pure XAML it hardly possible, so at least you can use some Converter. You don't need to know Data Model in converter i suppose.

Comment: @Spawn are you suggesting that I can send information about my controller to the converter and receive some indication from the latter about the row number I'm at? because I only know how to send actual data to my converters. any chance you can elaborate on your idea an perhaps give a code example?. thank you